# Why can't I buy adept+ level spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Am I bugged?

I'm a level 32 with conjuring at 100. I did the master quest that lets me buy permanent summons, but he will not sell me any adept or expert spells?

I am having the same problem with all other schools of magic even though they are all 65+.

I can't tell you how much it sucks running with perm thralls, while shooting out fire bolts!

Comment: you may have to wait for a shop reset before they start selling better stuff.  Try staying away from the college of winterhold for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you have to be level 35 before the Expert level spells become available to buy from Enthir or Faralda at the College of Winterhold.

verified on [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spells)

Wait until the shops reset now your level 35 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding but you are trying to buy Destruction spells from the Conjuration Master?

Check the wiki [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction), shows who you actually get the spells from.

Comment: No... I know where to go to get the right spells it's that no one will sell me any spells higher than apprentice lvl.

Comment: @Maalox I am nearing in on getting to master level myself, I will try and see what might be going wrong and update if I can. Sorry until then though that wiki is the best I can do.

Comment: Sad news... Stayed away from the college for 4 days... Leveled alcamy, leveled enchanting, leveled smithing... Took a 24 hour nap, now I am leve 35, and still no adapt or expert destruction spells to buy. I am now starting the staff of Magnus quest... Maybe after that... Or, does anyone know if you have to get along so far in the main quest before the better spells become active?